# Clicked image doesn't come to previous image after clicking it again

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html code  :

```
<img src="images/assets/plus.png"  alt="Earth" id="pic" class="portrait" onclick="changeImage()" />
```

Javascript:

```
 var newsrc = "minus.png";

 function changeImage() {
    if (newsrc == "minus.png") {
        document.images["pic"].src = "images/assets/minus.png";
        document.images["pic"].alt = "minus";
        newsrc = "minus.png";
    } else {
        document.images["pic"].src = "images/assets/plus.png";
        document.images["pic"].alt = "plus";
        newsrc = "plus.png";
    }
 }
```

I am using these code to change image onclick.Now i want that when i click the minus image again it will come back to plus image again .How can i do that?

Comment: instead of `==` use `!=` in `if (newsrc == "minus.png") {` simple logical error

Comment: If i want to use the same character for different image in same page what should i do now?

Comment: The problem is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `minus.png` then set to `minus.png`? Else won't be never performed. Should be if not minus, then minus, otherwise plus. Change `==` to `!=`. And if you want image with id "pic", you should use `getElementById()`.

**Edit:**

for multiple images use following and change `id="pic"` to `class="pic"` in `<img>`:

```
function changeImage() {
    if (newsrc != "minus.png") {
     for(var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("pic").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("pic")[i].src = "images/assets/minus.png";
        document.getElementsByClassName("pic")[i].alt = "minus";
     }
        newsrc = "minus.png";
    } else {
     for(var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("pic").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("pic")[i].src = "images/assets/plus.png";
        document.getElementsByClassName("pic")[i].alt = "plus";
     }
        newsrc = "plus.png";
    }
```

Comment: If i want the same character for two images what should i do? I want to use class "pic" not id "pic".What should i do? will code change?

Comment: Your code doesn't work.Please check .I couldn't find where is error in your code.

Comment: @user3649514 You also specifying class portrait. It should be `class="portrait pic"`, not `class="pic" class="portrait"`

Comment: @user3649514 Then tap the checkmark under vote count of my answer to make it green. It indicates that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `document.getElementById("pic")` instead of what you have because the `document.images[]` method returns an array. In your case it returns  "[object HTMLImageElement]".

You should also move `var newsrc = "minus.png"` inside your function. I'm not sure the function will recognize the variable the way you have it.

Finally you should not set the `newsrc` variable inside your if.

That being said this code is much more simplistic:

```
function changeImage() {
    var pic = document.getElementById("pic");
    var x = document.getElementById("pic").src;
    if (x == "images/assets/plus.png"){
        pic.src = "images/assets/minus.png"
        // Plus whatever else you want to do
    } else {pic.src = "images/assets/plus.png"
        // Plus whatever else you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: I want use class what should i do now?

Comment: Nevermind what I said about moving `var newsrc = "minus.png"` inside the function. Defining it globally should be fine.

Comment: Just use `document.getElementsByClassName("ClassNameHere")` but keep in mind that if you use class with your current code and you have other images with the same class name all those images will change as well.

Comment: "Defining it globally should be fine." Ehh. Global variables (and functions) should be avoided where possible. I will note that the OP could easily determine which state was active by simply checking the image's `alt` text or `.src` value. Also, `var pic = document.getElementById("pic"); ... pic.src = '...` is recommended.